# Connect to bluetooth headset programmatically Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I need to develop an wp8 app to connect to an bluetooth headset.
First, my application read the Mac address and the password (PIN) of the headset through a NFC tag. After that, I'll must connect to headset and play the music programmatically. I follow this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Bluetooth-app-to-device-644870ba) to make a connection, but the app doesn't work.
I try to change service name of the bluetooth connection to A2DP, but the magic doesn't happen.
How to fix this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you already paired the headset with your phone?  The sample only works with previously-paired Bluetooth devices.

Comment: ok, i found that the bluetooh is need to be paired before doing anything. My problem is need to automatic connect without pairing. In android there is a hack method to do this:), but widows phone seem not.